# How do I merge an array of Uint8Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typed-arrays

I have an array of several Uint8Arrays.
Something similar to this:

`[Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(8868)]`

How do I merge/concatenate/join (not sure what the right term is) them to a single ArrayBuffer?

The key here is that the output I need must be an ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 51):

You can use the `set` method. Create a new typed array with all the sizes.
Example:

```
var arrayOne = new Uint8Array([2,4,8]);
var arrayTwo = new Uint8Array([16,32,64]);

var mergedArray = new Uint8Array(arrayOne.length + arrayTwo.length);
mergedArray.set(arrayOne);
mergedArray.set(arrayTwo, arrayOne.length);
```

Alternative: Convert your typed array in "normal" arrays. concat it and create a type array of it again.

In your case (solution):

```
let myArrays = [new Uint8Array(16384), new Uint8Array(16384), new Uint8Array(16384), new Uint8Array(16384), new Uint8Array(16384), new Uint8Array(8868)];

// Get the total length of all arrays.
let length = 0;
myArrays.forEach(item => {
  length += item.length;
});

// Create a new array with total length and merge all source arrays.
let mergedArray = new Uint8Array(length);
let offset = 0;
myArrays.forEach(item => {
  mergedArray.set(item, offset);
  offset += item.length;
});

// Should print an array with length 90788 (5x 16384 + 8868 your source arrays)
console.log(mergedArray);
```

Comment: One mistake: ```offset =``` should be ```offset +=```. And a subjective remark: you could use ```forEach``` for the second loop too (```mergedArray.set(item,offset);offset+=item.length;```)

Comment: This is 10 times faster than the using the spread syntax. https://jsben.ch/jze3P

Answer (score 30):

Just treat it like any normal array:

```
var concatArray = new Uint8Array([ ...Uint8Array1, ...Uint8Array2, ...Uint8Array3 ]);
```

Comment: See performance comparison of spread syntax vs the set method as proposed by @Dominik: https://jsben.ch/jze3P

Comment: In the performance test above, the mergedArray.set is only doing 27 times better than the spread syntax. Easy.

Answer (score 4):

There has an easy way:

```
await new Blob([a1,a2,a3]).arraybuffer();
```

but slow then:

```
new Uint8Array(a1.length + a2.length + a3.length)
..set(a1,0)
..set(a2,a1.length)
..set(a3,a1.length+a2.length)
```

Comment: a small typo, or could be a newer version `await new Blob([a1,a2,a3]).arrayBuffer()`

Comment: "but slow then" means "but it is slower than:" or does it mean "but if it's slow, then instead do:" ?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a helper function to concatenate an array of arrays of any length, in their provided order.

This looks nice and clean but it also makes copy of `acc` on each iteration because of the spread operator:

```
// arrays are Uint8Array[]
(arrays) => new Uint8Array(arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []));
```

This looks a little longer, but is more performant since `acc` is not spread on each iteration, but pushed to and returned:

```
// arrays are Uint8Array[]
(arrays) => {
  const flatNumberArray = arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(...curr);
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return new Uint8Array(flatNumberArray);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

By extending @Domske approach, I did create a function that merge N `Uint8Array`s into a single one:

```js
function mergeUint8Arrays(...arrays) {
  const totalSize = arrays.reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.length, 0);
  const merged = new Uint8Array(totalSize);

  arrays.forEach((array, i, arrays) => {
    const offset = arrays.slice(0, i).reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.length, 0);
    merged.set(array, offset);
  });

  return merged;
}
```

Typescript:

```
function mergeUint8Arrays(...arrays: Uint8Array[]): Uint8Array {
  const totalSize = arrays.reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.length, 0);
  const merged = new Uint8Array(totalSize);

  arrays.forEach((array, i, arrays) => {
    const offset = arrays.slice(0, i).reduce((acc, e) => acc + e.length, 0);
    merged.set(array, offset);
  });

  return merged;
}
```

---

Usage:

```js
const arrayOne = new Uint8Array([2,4,8]);
const arrayTwo = new Uint8Array([16,32,64]);

mergeUint8Arrays(arrayOne, arrayTwo); // Uint8Array(6) [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: single_array is what you want

```
 var arrays = [Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(16384), Uint8Array(8868)]



 var single_array = concat(arrays)


function concat(arrays) {
  // sum of individual array lengths
  let totalLength = arrays.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value.length, 0);

  if (!arrays.length) return null;

   let result = new Uint8Array(totalLength);

      // for each array - copy it over result
      // next array is copied right after the previous one
      let length = 0;
      for(let array of arrays) {
            result.set(array, length);
            length += array.length;
      }

      return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Function based on Dominik's answer:

```
function mergeUInt8Arrays(a1: Uint8Array, a2: Uint8Array): Uint8Array {
  // sum of individual array lengths
  var mergedArray = new Uint8Array(a1.length + a2.length);
  mergedArray.set(a1);
  mergedArray.set(a2, a1.length);
  return mergedArray;
}
```