# How to effectively concat Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, gif, typed-arrays

I'm trying to create a GIF image from scratch on the browser. It all works, but it get a lot of time to build small image which feels underwhelming. (2.6s for a 300x200 with 100 frames on a high-end proc)

Currently, I'm concatenating all my data into a simple `Array` and turn everything into a `Uint8Array` when done. I guess using `Uint8Array` would be better memory and efficiency wise, but I didn't figured out how to concat my data as I create it.

I tried to recreate the `Uint8Array` each times, but it obviously reduces performances. I tried to use `Stream`, but never manage to make it work.

```
// kinda concat
stream = new Uint8Array([
    ...stream,
    ...graphicControlExtension,
    ...imageDescriptor,
]);
```

MDN `Stream` example are just confusing, so if someone could point me to the right direction it would be dope. =D

Comment: what are `stream`, `graphicControlExtension` etc? Strings, other arrays?

Comment: That's the point of my question. They're `Array` as of now, but concatenating everything take too long IMO. There should be a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge an array of Uint8Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129643/how-do-i-merge-an-array-of-uint8arrays)

Comment: best answer for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57946167/470749

Answer (score 1):

if all of your variables are uint 8 arrays(stream, graphicControlExtension, imageDescriptor) use the set method.

```
uint8stream = new Uint8Array(stream.length + graphicsControlExtension.length + imageDescriptor.length);
uint8stream.set(stream);
uint8stream.set(graphicControlExtension, stream.length);
uint8stream.set(imageDescriptor, stream.length + graphicControlExtension.length);
```

Otherwise you should to convert them first

UPD:
to boost it up you can:

1. try to use push instead of concat
2. try to use lodash.concat (it is faster than Array.prototype.concat)
3. write your own concat method like in [this](https://dev.to/uilicious/javascript-array-push-is-945x-faster-than-array-concat-1oki) article

Comment: This is the same as my example code. You just create a new `Uint8Array` and fill it with the values or I'm missing something.

Comment: I tried `push`, with the same results. I just also tried to make a custom concat method, with the same results.
My problem is (I think) that I'm dealing with a lot of values, not that push/concat/spread is not performant.
I guess I should be using [`Stream`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API), but I don't know how.

Comment: This example has a mistake: you need to specify the size of the Uint8Array to be at least the total size of the sub arrays, otherwise `set` will not work because it expects the array to have enough elements. Also, are you sure that the copy at the end is the bottleneck? Make sure to profile this.