# How to decrypt large files (1 GB) with AES-CTR chunk by chunk in javascript (browsers)?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

We are trying to decrypt large files (1GB) in browsers. With AES-CTR it should be possible to decrypt chunk by chunk - where chunk must be the correct size and you also have to provide nonce + counter.
Does anyone have any examples or ideas how to do this in javascript?

What we tried so far:

```
var length = value.byteLength;
var chunkSize = 128;
var index = 0;
let chunks = [];
let aesCounter = byteArrayToLong(subtleIv);
do {
    let newCount = aesCounter + index / 16;
    var decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "AES-CTR", counter: Buffer.from(longToByteArray(newCount)), length: chunkSize}, subtleKey, value.slice(index, index+chunkSize));
    chunks.push(Buffer.from(decrypted));
    index += chunkSize;
} while(index < length);
let newCount = aesCounter + index / 16;
decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "AES-CTR", counter: Buffer.from(longToByteArray(newCount)), length: chunkSize}, subtleKey, value.slice(index, index+chunkSize));
chunks.push(Buffer.from(decrypted));

let decryptedAll = Buffer.concat(chunks);


function longToByteArray(/*long*/long) {
    var byteArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    for ( var index = 0; index < byteArray.length; index ++ ) {
        var byte = long & 0xff;
        byteArray [ index ] = byte;
        long = (long - byte) / 256 ;
    }

    return byteArray;
}

function byteArrayToLong(/*byte[]*/byteArray) {
    var value = 0;
    for ( var i = byteArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        value = (value * 256) + byteArray[i];
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Topaco I just edited the question with the code we have so far.

Comment: If you're not stuck on WebCrypto, [this](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#progressive-ciphering) may be a more comfortable approach for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only flaw in your implementation is actually the conversion between integer and byte array. Firstly, in JavaScript the maximum integer is 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307179/9014097), secondly, even with smaller numbers the little endian order is used, but the WebCrypto API applies the big endian order.

As a first step to a fix you could use e.g. the [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) implementation of JavaScript and the [here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/convert-js-bigints-to-typedarrays/) described conversion between `BigInt` and `ArrayBuffer`.
Since this implementation works with `ArrayBuffer` and `Uint8Array` respectively, an implementation for concatenation is needed, e.g. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129872/9014097).

This changes your implementation slightly as follows (key, IV and ciphertext are imported hex encoded):

```js
(async () => {

// Key import
var keyHex = "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f";
var key = hex2ab(keyHex);
var subtleKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw", 
    key,
    { name: "AES-CTR" },
    false, 
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"] 
);

// IV import
var ivHex = "404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f";
var subtleIv = hex2ab(ivHex);

// Ciphertext import
var ciphertextHex = "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";
var ciphertext = hex2ab(ciphertextHex); 

// Decrypt and concat
var length = ciphertext.byteLength;
var chunkSize = 128; // chunkSize in bytes
var index = 0;
var chunks = [];
var aesCounter = bufToBn(subtleIv);
do {
    var newCount = aesCounter + BigInt(index / 16); // index / 16 = number of blocks
    var decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "AES-CTR", counter: bnToBuf(newCount), length: 128}, subtleKey, ciphertext.slice(index, index+chunkSize)); // length in bits
    chunks.push(new Uint8Array(decrypted));
    index += chunkSize;
} while(index < length);
var mergedChunks = merge(chunks);

// Decode and output
var decrypted = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, mergedChunks);
console.log(decrypted);

// https://coolaj86.com/articles/convert-js-bigints-to-typedarrays/
function bnToBuf(bn) {
    var hex = BigInt(bn).toString(16);
    if (hex.length % 2) { hex = '0' + hex; }
    var len = hex.length / 2;
    var u8 = new Uint8Array(len);
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        u8[i] = parseInt(hex.slice(j, j+2), 16);
        i += 1;
        j += 2;
    }
    return u8;
}
function bufToBn(buf) {
    var hex = [];
    u8 = Uint8Array.from(buf);
    u8.forEach(function (i) {
        var h = i.toString(16);
        if (h.length % 2) { h = '0' + h; }
        hex.push(h);
    });
    return BigInt('0x' + hex.join(''));
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129872/9014097
function merge(chunks){
    let size = 0;
    chunks.forEach(item => {
        size += item.length;
    });
    let mergedArray = new Uint8Array(size);
    let offset = 0;
    chunks.forEach(item => {
        mergedArray.set(item, offset);
        offset += item.length;
    });
    return mergedArray;
}

function hex2ab(hex){
    return new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {
        return parseInt(h, 16)}));
}

})();
```

which successfully decrypts the ciphertext. Btw, the ciphertext was generated with [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f%27%7D,%27CTR%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=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).

---

Unlike the WebCrypto API, CryptoJS supports progressive encryption, so the same logic can be implemented significantly easier with CryptoJS:

```js
// Key import
var keyHex = "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f";
var keyWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(keyHex);

// IV import
var ivHex = "404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f";
var ivWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ivHex);

// Ciphertext import
var ciphertextHex = "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";
var ciphertextWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertextHex);

// Decrypt and concat
var length = ciphertextWA.sigBytes;
var chunkSize = 128;
var index = 0;
var decryptedWA = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("");
var aesDecryptor = CryptoJS.algo.AES.createDecryptor(keyWA, { iv: ivWA, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding });
var chunk = null;
do {   
    chunk = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(ciphertextWA.words.slice(index/4, (index + chunkSize)/4));
    decryptedWA = decryptedWA.concat(aesDecryptor.process(chunk));
    index += chunkSize;
} while(index < length - chunkSize);
chunk = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(ciphertextWA.words.slice(index/4, (index + chunkSize)/4));
chunk.sigBytes = length - index;
chunk.clamp();
decryptedWA = decryptedWA.concat(aesDecryptor.process(chunk));
decryptedWA = decryptedWA.concat(aesDecryptor.finalize());

// Decode and output
var decrypted = decryptedWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decrypted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

---

A drawback of the first variant is that the `BigInt` class should actually not be used in the context of cryptography, since the operations are not constant-time, which results in a vulnerability to timing attacks. So, here you would have to apply a cryptographically more secure JavaScript BigInteger implementation for production.
For such reasons, the use of an established library (as opposed to a custom implementation), such as CryptoJS, is generally more secure (although ultimately vulnerabilities cannot be ruled out here either).

Answer (score 0):

You are well on your way; cutting the ciphertext in chunks of C-blocks and then updating the counter block according to the block count is exactly what you should be doing.

However, note that the counter block is 128 bits: the `longToByteArray` should be called `createCounterBlock(nonce, counter)`. The nonce should be contained in the **initial/leftmost** (8?) bytes. The counter is encoded as unsigned big endian in the **final/rightmost** 8 bytes, making 16 bytes total. This you can then provide as an IV to decrypt the chunk.

Currently your counter is placed in the leftmost bytes, which will fail for most CTR implementations; I don't think that JS uses 128 bit integers. Officially the contents of the counter block is not defined, but generally a big endian 128 bit value is used.