# cast/convert ReadableStream<Uint8Array> to Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, deno, whatwg-streams-api

I have a `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` and need to convert it to `Uint8ClampedArray` in TypeScript Deno.

I tried some solutions I could find. Like this:

```
const getImageData = image => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (context != null) {
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  }
};
```

But it already fails because `document` can't be found.

Is there a straight forward casting/converting from `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` to `Uint8ClampedArray`?

My ReadableStream comes from this:

```
const image = (await fetch(url)).body!;
```

I want to do all this, to create a [`blurhash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blurhash). But when just using the `Uint8Array` I get `ValidationError: Width and height must match the pixels array`

Comment: What does `getImageData` and drawing to a canvas have to do with a `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) and don't know the byte length of the stream, then you can collect the bytes and concatenate them in order to construct an instance of [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray):

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PQKhAIGEHsDsGcCuBbApvcAXAFq89MAnVAQ2XBGACgT4BPWAY3ADNEnMBLOcT2TaAFU+mAByQANmQAOqACYBBQoRJ0AFFQCQxEnJIAjCagBc4AEqk9h1AGUipZAB5h-UUpV0AfABoqASlMABUJoZE54VGcRcSlkWUVlVU9wAG8tRjgCcEZsdgBreFMXMXdVAG0AXXAAXnBKgG4tI0xsxEJ4aEIa8AAGRq0SAHcSThadKyMAOmlOWQAVaA1NTVhUQfAAdUJRgyM7HWQ1NOXNQe3MVDUc-L9UrRPGNo6ugGpa69g8yf06C4AZVCwADmOEaJ00HwK00Q8GwV1ynz8YOWAF9fKi-OikVR0pkWoxYvFuqt1sUYjJ5KV1I92p1sRCnp1un0cZoWEyrnjsgi8uBoCxufl4LdjhDCfJJhFMPD8t5WrTCPSGQrwG9BZ9vr9UADgaCtCjWcRMG1YNlxXJGgaqATaBg-tAgTY+LzUAAPC6wOQYLY7az7Bx3CF4wiIRgCQhqEX3JCyCOi07nS6QqPgjIIaBTCQOmWI5GaNH3FH0g1Wm3wDAKCTSbAGVCYQIjQj+sjgN0er3mSy7Wz2MhRVxU5LHNMEENhzqRwOaZrZaByVCBaAiboAIhIK8mGXni5ECmlPT8AEJkSOWiw+CQJDBt0v+KuAF4brcL2+YPdqA-H6OIWNHe6aaREAkCROX4EJgNQRUp2WNMiAzIxCEmQEAEdEFQNC1BJcAySpNQymfHd+BeF45QI19iIqPwlWWTgBU5G9l2Sc9YEva8XxEW5YPAhDNyzCJIzzAsMTBEscSBLN9EvOZsHCSYWDrHJujYDhuFNZBoEYPIADEFLhFMjRNcBglCcJUEmYgOgkAA3S57iwix4GkTJLiwytq1retG2bQ5MWg3BdEgwpwCwgAJSxArw-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-HL+ZFiw+1HWdDvLRxIa+ApoA)

```ts
/** Consumes the stream */
async function intoUint8ClampedArray(
  readable: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>,
): Promise<Uint8ClampedArray> {
  const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
  let cursor = 0;

  await readable.pipeTo(
    new WritableStream({
      write(chunk) {
        cursor += chunk.byteLength;
        chunks.push(chunk);
      },
    }),
  );

  const clamped = new Uint8ClampedArray(cursor);
  cursor = 0;

  for (const chunk of chunks) {
    clamped.set(chunk, cursor);
    cursor += chunk.byteLength;
  }

  return clamped;
}
```

Use it with your example code like this:

```ts
const response = await fetch("https://example.com/");

if (!response.body) {
  // Handle case where body is null here…
  throw new Error("Body null");
}

const clamped = await intoUint8ClampedArray(response.body);

// Use the Uint8ClampedArray…
```

---

However, if you're starting with an instance of [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) then you can use its async method [`arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer) to construct the clamped array more simply:

```ts
const response = await fetch("https://example.com/");
const clamped = new Uint8ClampedArray(await response.arrayBuffer());
// Use the Uint8ClampedArray…
```

Comment: "*you can read all the bytes into a plain array*" - that doesn't sound very efficient. Is there no way to do something like `Buffer.concat(arrayOfChunks)` in Deno?

Comment: I tried the second solution. Sadly I get `TypeError: Body already consumed.`. But before executing your second line, I already use the response for something else. I didn't know that this would be a problem. I use the `response.body`

Comment: Can I use the arraybuffer and convert it into the `UInt8Array` for my other purpose and into the `ClampedArray`?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145952/cast-convert-readablestreamuint8array-to-uint8clampedarray?noredirect=1#comment137779522_78150903) @Bergi Yes, Deno (which offers Node compat) can do that, but my answer was written to apply to browsers, too.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145952/cast-convert-readablestreamuint8array-to-uint8clampedarray?noredirect=1#comment137780448_78150903) @progNewbie Yes, you can only consume a response body once. You can either use [`response.clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) or [`readableStream.tee()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/tee) to create a copy.

Comment: Thanks. I used `.clone()` which works. I ran into the next error now but I guess this is another topic.

Comment: @jsejcksn Yeah [concatenating buffers in plain js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49129643/1048572) is rather ugly

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78145952/cast-convert-readablestreamuint8array-to-uint8clampedarray/78150903?noredirect=1#comment137781576_78150903) @Bergi I've updated the algorithm to reflect your suggestion.